# Supercollider 2D array : generative nesting : wrap / size issues

Tags: c++, arrays, nested, iteration, supercollider

I'm learning SuperCollider and I'm having a problem while trying to create a 2D array for storing frequencies... Initially I wanted the array to be 12 x 9 such that the rows represent notes (c, d, e, f...) and the columns represent octaves, e.g. f[0,0] = c0 , f[1,5] = c#5 , f[2,1] = d1 , etc. First off, SC natively wraps left to right through the rows, so there's my first problem (to be solved later).

Main problem: my attempts at nesting for() or while() loops to iterate over 3 indices to manually place the frequencies into array locations has failed miserably. I know this is full of holes. Sry/thx. Code below.

```
//loading the frequency array with note values
(
f = Array.new(108);
for ( -57,50, { arg n; 
    f.add(440 * (( 2 ** (1/12)) ** (n)) );
} );
)

/* below attempt works, sort of... values in the 
expected 12x9 array are what they're supposed to 
be, but there are extra values, in that the array 
size is larger than expected... e.g. k[0,9] should 
return null, right? Don't want the array values 
to wrap such that the first row is (108) entries 
long!
*/

k = Array2D.fromArray(12,9,f);
k[0,0]; //returns proper entry
k[0,9]; //should be null???
k[0,107]; //shouldn't exist??
k[11,8]; //returns proper entry

/* attempts at manual entry, array size is too 
large after 2nd for() loop is executed and double 
entries exist in the array, which is now bigger 
than it was initialized...
*/

h = Array2D.new(12,9);
for ( 0,8, { arg n; h.put(0,n,f[n]);} );
for ( 0,8, { arg n; h.put(1,n,f[n+12]); } );


//nested iteration attempted 1

(
f = Array.new(108);
for (-57, 50, { arg n;
    f.add(440 * (( 2 ** (1/12) ) ** n) );
} );
q = Array2D.new(12,9);

for (0, 11, { arg i;
    for (0, 8, { arg j;
        for (0, 107, { arg k;
            q.put(0,j,f[k]);
            q[0,j].postln;
        });
    });
});
)


//nested iteration attempt 2

(
for (0, 107, { arg i;
    for (0, 11, { arg j;
        for (0, 8, { arg k;
            q.put(j,k,f[i]);
            q[j,k].postln;
//              k = k+1;
        });
//          j = j+1;
    });
//      i = i+1;
});
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to build your array as you are doing, but you're missing out on some of the better language features of SuperCollider, that make expressing concepts like this very straightforward.

When constructing arrays, the `collect` method can be very useful:

```
var octaves = (1..7); // array of numbers 1..7
var degrees = (0..11);
var table = octaves.collect {
  |oct|
  degrees.collect {
    |degree|
    // Table value calculation here
  }
}:

table[3][2]; // Octave three, degree two
```

SuperCollider also has ample support the kinds of musical note / frequency conversion you're doing by hand - there's no need to re-invent the wheel here, take a look at the Scale class, and methods like |degreeToFreq| and |midiCps|.